# Filtering on node property in long distance path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Starting from an item recommended by people, is there a way to filter on a person property, such as age, while traversing at long distance friendship relationships?
For instance in the following cypher query, I'd like to only traverse nodes of person +18y, not just filtering on p's age.

```
MATCH path = (:Fruit {Name: 'Apple'}) <-[:LIKES]- (:Person) -[:FRIENDOF*1..5]- (p:Person) -[:LIKES]-> (:Device {Name: 'iPhone'}) return path
```

**UPDATE** more details :

In this exemple the graph contains molecules and scaffolds resulting of stripping off side chains and rings recursively.

```
MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN path
```

[image]

Molecules are shown in blue and scaffold in red named after their number of rings. As we can see, starting from mol25, we have a structure with a single ring at two edges distance.

Hence, I filter on the number of rings:

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN p
```

We get the same picture! The scaffold bearing a single ring is still present. Worse is to come!

[image]

Now we extract distinct scaffold nodes from using the previous queries, first without filtering on number of rings.

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN distinct id(s) as ID, s.Name, s.Size, s.Num_Rings
```

We expect 7 scaffold nodes in return... we only get 4. Filtering on number of rings returns the same results.

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN DISTINCT id(s), s.Name, s.Size, s.Num_Rings
```

Starting from another molecule than mol25 and using UNWIND to extract nodes from the path, it properly returns all scaffold nodes and filtered one without and with the WHERE condition respectively.

```
MATCH p=(m:Molecule) -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-> (s:Scaffold) 
WHERE id(m)=9 and s.Num_Rings > 1 
UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
RETURN id(n), n.Name, n.Num_Rings, n.Size, n.Smiles
```

But again, returning the path p instead we get the correct graph when restricting on the -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-> direction, but not without the direction restriction -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-.

I'd appreciate if anyone would help sorting this out.

[image]

Comment: I added your answer/reply to the question for people landing to the page, seeing my answer with the original question could not have been so obious to them :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some points here :

> Hence, I filter on the number of rings:

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN p
```

Don't forget that by specifying variable length paths, it is totally possible that the path going from `mol25` to `scaffold4` to `scaffold1` to other `scaffold4` and then to other `molecule` will be valid, as the end of the edge is a molecule and the node before has a `Num_Rings > 1`, indepedently of the other intermediate nodes values of Num_Rings.

So the intermediate nodes can be anything, if you want to restrict to the scaffolds with a value > 1, you should use a `ALL` clause :

This query seems to do the trick based with the following Neo4j console : http://console.neo4j.org/r/7f5hc4   (property values a bit different but yeah..)

```
MATCH p=(m:Molecule { id: 566 })-[r:HAS_SUBSTRUCTURE*1..3]-(s:Scaffold)<-[:HAS_SUBSTRUCTURE]-(:Molecule)
USING INDEX m:Molecule(id)
WHERE ALL (x IN tail(nodes(p))[0..size(nodes(p))-2] 
           WHERE 'Scaffold' IN labels(x) AND x.rings > 29)
RETURN p
```

Explanations :

- Match the path like you do
- USING INDEX, by my tests with PROFILE, I saw the molecule(id) index was not used, so I help Cypher a bit
- The `tail(nodes(p))[0..size(nodes(p))-2]` are the nodes in the path between the two molecules, note that `nodes(p)[1..size(nodes(p))-2]` is equivalent
- I assert that these nodes have `ALL` the label scaffold and a Num_Rings value > 29 (here 29 because it is randomized from Graphgen)

Comment: Merci Christophe, I don't see any WHERE ALL exemple in the manual, seems promising answer. With the first exemple, would you write the following: MATCH path = (:Fruit {Name: 'Apple'}) <-[:LIKES]- (:Person) -[:FRIENDOF*1..5]- (p:Person) -[:LIKES]-> (:Device {Name: 'iPhone'}) WHERE ALL (x IN nodes(path) WHERE x.Age > 18) return path

Comment: No I wouldn't because the fruit is also a node in the path and don't have an age, hence is why I do tail(nodes(p))

Comment: Alternate solution, because tail would not always match the scaffold node since we traverse both ways -[:hasSubstructure]- we can use: MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'triazolam'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) WHERE ALL (x IN nodes(p) WHERE NOT HAS(x.Num_Rings) OR x.Num_Rings > 0) RETURN p

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can use a simple `WHERE` clause, and filter appropriately.

```
MATCH path = (:Fruit {Name: 'Apple'})<-[:LIKES]-
             (intermed:Person)-[:FRIENDOF*1..5]-(p:Person)
             -[:LIKES]->(:Device {Name: 'iPhone'}) 
WHERE intermed.age >= 18 AND
      p.age >= 18
return path
```

Comment: Indeed, this was my first guess too, however I get weird results. When I return distinct :Person nodes, I only see those over 18, conversely, when I return path, the displayed graph contains unexpected people (<18y). See below on an other exemple.

Comment: By the way, your intermediate person would only let me filter on the age of people who liked an apple, not on their friends, I'd like to only traverse nodes of >18y people. See the exemple on molecules and scaffolds below.

Comment: Even restricting people to 18+ hence traversing doesn't return the correct path: MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.Age > 18 WITH p MATCH path=((:Fruit {Name: 'Apple'}) <-[:LIKES*1..5]- (p) -[:LIKES]-> (:Device {Name: 'iPhone'}) RETURN path

Comment: I'm not following what's wrong with this.  Yes, it limits intermediate nodes to age >= 18.  Wasn't that the point?  What I'm missing here is what is the correct path you want returned?

Comment: The molecule answer below appears to be entirely unrelated to fruits and people and devices.  Is your actual domain the molecule setup?  You may want to edit your question with the molecule setup, and then delete that answer as it doesn't even seem at all related to the original question

Comment: You would do the path from `0..4` if you have the end node being treated also as intermediate node and then you can just test your predicates on `p`

Comment: @FrobberOfBits, both exemples actually suffer the same issue, what I would like to do is traversing [:FREINDOF] edges in one case and [:hasSubstructure] in the other case stopping on nodes (in the whole path) that do not fulfill requirements (e.g. Age or Num_Rings). In the first exemple it prevents recommending good restaurants to adultes based on kids likeness and friendships. The molecular exemple is more complex to explain in few words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a long answer, with more details.

In this exemple the graph contains molecules and scaffolds resulting of stripping off side chains and rings recursively.

```
MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN path
```

[image]

Molecules are shown in blue and scaffold in red named after their number of rings. As we can see, starting from mol25, we have a structure with a single ring at two edges distance.

Hence, I filter on the number of rings:

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN p
```

We get the same picture! The scaffold bearing a single ring is still present. Worse is to come!

[image]

Now we extract distinct scaffold nodes from using the previous queries, first without filtering on number of rings.

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN distinct id(s) as ID, s.Name, s.Size, s.Num_Rings
```

We expect 7 scaffold nodes in return... we only get 4. Filtering on number of rings returns the same results.

```
MATCH p=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN DISTINCT id(s), s.Name, s.Size, s.Num_Rings
```

Starting from another molecule than mol25 and using UNWIND to extract nodes from the path, it properly returns all scaffold nodes and filtered one without and with the WHERE condition respectively.

```
MATCH p=(m:Molecule) -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-> (s:Scaffold) 
WHERE id(m)=9 and s.Num_Rings > 1 
UNWIND nodes(p) as n 
RETURN id(n), n.Name, n.Num_Rings, n.Size, n.Smiles
```

But again, returning the path p instead we get the correct graph when restricting on the -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-> direction, but not without the direction restriction -[:hasSubstructure*1..4]-.

I'd appreciate if anyone would help sorting this out.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible to export the subgraph with the shell in order for us to have a console to play with ? ./bin/neo4j-shell -c 'dump MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN path' > cypher.export  ....... and post the content of the file or paste it in a neo4j console and share the link ?

Comment: Also, please note that the neo4j browser auto-complete edges by default in the visualization, you can de-activate it by turning-it off in the bottom of each visualisation box http://imgur.com/Fs3p9Ky

Comment: There is a gist here https://gist.github.com/pducrot/a26ab73f4bf49574ab38 with similar data, however, the easiest for you would be to create a dummy graph with items and people, people like a few items and have friends, hence you'd try extract items liked by secondary or tertiary friends traversing only over 18y people. This was the original question of this post.

Comment: Nice catch Pierre ;-)