# Optional match issues

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm confused on how to properly use OPTIONAL MATCH. Using the same exemple reported earlier ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619173/filtering-on-node-property-in-long-distance-path)), I would like starting from mol25 to traverse its scaffolds and return optionally linked other molecules.

```
MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (s) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN path
```

[image]

Although scaffold -1796602943 (top-left) is a substructure of mol26, mol26 is not return. I would have expected OPTIONAL MATCH (s) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) to return it.

When using WITH before OPTIONAL MATCH, I get all molecules bearing any of scaffolds s, but the scaffold hierarchy is then limited to the first neighbors, which is the expected behavior.

```
MATCH (:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) 
WITH s 
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(s) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) 
RETURN p
```

So, how can I get scaffolds at three relationships distance and molecules optionally attached to any of these in a single path (required for subsequent treatment)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think if you want to return the other molecule, you actually have to `RETURN` it:

```
MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'})-[:hasSubstructure*1..3]-(s:Scaffold) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[:hasSubstructure]-(other:Molecule) 
RETURN path, other
```

Comment: You're right, however I'd like all traversed nodes and edges to be reported in one single path for subsequent treatment. My second query was meant to show that other molecules are related to some scaffolds. Why wouldn't the first query return expected scaffolds and molecules?

Comment: It doesn't return because you don't return anything from the `OPTIONAL MATCH`... if you want to combine the results later, have a look at http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html

Comment: Do you mean that in the following command, OPTIONAL MATCH do not belong to the path ? MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) - :hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s:Scaffold) OPTIONAL MATCH (s) <- :hasSubstructure]- (:Molecule) WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 RETURN path

Comment: Apparently not ... just give it a name and return it.

Comment: Hmmm... to my opinion it's a drawback, previously with version 1.9 or less, one would use a "?" to optionally match with better results and clearer queries. I think it's pretty disappointing that MATCH path=(:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'})-[:hasSubstructure*1..3]-(s:Scaffold) 
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 would not filter (stop traversing) :Scaffold nodes on the Num_Rings property.

Answer (score 0):

Following on the above recommendation, let's add a name and return attached molecules.

```
MATCH (s:Scaffold) WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 WITH s
MATCH p=((:Molecule {Name: 'mol25'}) -[:hasSubstructure*1..3]- (s)) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (s) <-[:hasSubstructure]- (m:Molecule)
WHERE s.Num_Rings > 1 
RETURN p,m
```

It still doesn't return the expected graph, molecules are properly returned, addition scaffolds are returned as well, but still scaffold with Num_Rings = 1 are traversed.

[image]